# CS0234 Error on runtime, for classes in the same assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an ASP.NET 4 Web Application Project. This project contains a number of pages. After having made some changes I get an error at runtime (ASP.NET Compile time) that this or that namespace cannot be found.

At design time (in Visual Studio 2010) there is no problem for Intellisense to see these namespaces and classes, which are in the project assembly themselves. And there is no problems at compile time in Visual Studio either.

Comment: Could you show your code? *this and that namespace* is not very precise problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer I received for a very similar question and see if this does the trick for you (it did for me!):

[.Net Extension Method (this string Foo) Only Partially Visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161948/net-extension-method-this-string-foo-only-partially-visible)

Comment: Afraid not. This just moved the error from the using statement in the code, to the namespace declaration in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

This will be a page compilation error. The reason it works fine at design/compile time is because page compilation does not happen then...it happens at runtime.

You need to look into the [`compilation.assemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) configuration and [`pages.namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms164642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which let you configure the assemblies and namespaces used in the generated code for pages. The other way to ensure assemblies are referenced during page compilation is to mark them as **"Copy Local"** in your solution.